# Resize Window to X Characters (not pixels)

Tags: c, gtk

[`gtk_window_set_default_size()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-default-size) resizes the window based off of pixels. How would I do this if I wanted to resize it based on x amount of characters, and possibly taking into account the font size?

From what I have gathered searching on the internet, [`gtk_window_set_geometry_hints()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-geometry-hints) seems to be based off of pixels too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always convert characters to pixels by obtaining the [approximate char width](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Fonts.html#pango-font-metrics-get-approximate-char-width) from the font.

Starting with a relevant widget (such as a text view or whatever it is that holds the characters you actually care about), call `gtk_widget_get_pango_context`, then `pango_context_load_font` to get the font, `pango_font_get_metrics` to get the font metrics, and finally `pango_font_metrics_get_approximate_char_width` divided by `PANGO_SCALE` to get the char width. Demonstrated in PyGTK:

```
import gtk, pango

char_count = 80     # how many characters you have

w = gtk.Window()    # here you'd use another widget
ctx = w.get_pango_context()
metrics = ctx.load_font(ctx.get_font_description()).get_metrics()
char_width_pango = metrics.get_approximate_char_width()
pixel_count = char_count * char_width_pango / pango.SCALE
print pixel_count
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, although the syntax is a little different for C. Either way, thanks for introducing me to this PANGO library

Comment: @halexh What did you use for height? I now see that there doesn't seem to be a `pango_font_metrics_get_approximate_char_height`.

Comment: Ironically, I only needed to deal with the width. It is odd that there isnt a similar function for the height. Maybe [pango_font_metrics_get_ascent](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Fonts.html#pango-font-metrics-get-ascent)?

Comment: @halexh It's probably easier to obtain the exact height, so no "approximate" function is needed. Ascent is the distance from baseline to the top, and what one would need for height is baseline to baseline (or top-to-top, etc.). What we think of "height" might be ascent+descent.